# ViewHolder + ListView Scrolling Shuffling Text

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I know this has been repeatedly asked on StackOverflow, but I've gone through a bunch of questions/answers and can't really figure out what the problem is with my code. Here is the getView code within my custom adapter:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friend_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_pic);
        holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
        holder.num_classes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shared_classes);         
        holder.text.setTypeface(face);
        holder.num_classes.setTypeface(lightface);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // Build Shared Classes text
    FriendDataHolder fdh = getItem(position);

    String classesText = fdh.getClassesText();      
    if(classesText != "") holder.num_classes.setText(classesText);

    holder.text.setText(fdh.getName());


    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    String imageUrl= "http://graph.facebook.com/" + getItemId(position) + "/picture?type=square";

    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.fb_default)
    .into(holder.image);

    return view;
}
```

The interesting thing I can't figure out is that neither my Image/Name gets mixed up, but only the Classes text. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(classesText != "") holder.num_classes.setText(classesText);// this is the problem,
```

if u set a value say "test" for item 1 and the 10th item is reusing the view, if the classesText is empty or null, then u do not update the value, therefore it would show "test" for 10th item also have an else case to set empty text or a default value

```
if(classesText != "") holder.num_classes.setText(classesText); else {holder.num.classes.setText("")}
```

Comment: Whoops, such a simple mistake I've definitely been coding for too long! Thanks so much, I'll accept the answer when the 10 min time limit expires

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this

```
if(classesText != "") holder.num_classes.setText(classesText);
```

With

```
if(classesText != "") {holder.num_classes.setText(classesText);} 
else {holder.num.classes.setText("")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

          ViewHolder holder;
            if ((view == null) || (view.getTag() == null)) { // UPDATE HERE
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friend_list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_pic);
                holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
                holder.num_classes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shared_classes);         
                holder.text.setTypeface(face);
                holder.num_classes.setTypeface(lightface);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            // Build Shared Classes text
            FriendDataHolder fdh = getItem(position);

            String classesText = fdh.getClassesText();      
            if(classesText != "") holder.num_classes.setText(classesText);

            holder.text.setText(fdh.getName());


            // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
            String imageUrl= "http://graph.facebook.com/" + getItemId(position) + "/picture?type=square";

            Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.fb_default)
            .into(holder.image);

            view.setTag(holder); // updata here

            return view;



    }
```